# Does $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x - \sin x}$ exist?

Tags: limits

**Q:** Does $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x-\sin x}$ exist?

My book says it exists and equals $0$, but I think otherwise. Here is my argument:

I’ll separately consider the left and the right limits.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{x- \sin x} \\ = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \sqrt{(h+\epsilon) - h} \\ =0$$ This follows because $x \gt \sin x$ for $x \gt 0$, with the difference between the two decreasing as $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$.

Further,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt{x-\sin x} \\
= \lim_{h\to 0^-} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\sqrt{(h-\epsilon) -h} \\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \sqrt{-\epsilon}$$

This follows as $x \lt \sin x$ for $x\lt 0$.

Now, this is clearly not a real number, or maybe the right way to say this is that it’s not defined in the real world. And so we can say that the left and right limits are not equal, and the limit doesn’t exist.

Is my argument correct? If not, where am I wrong?

Comment: The domain of this function over the reals is $[0,\infty)$ so this limit is equivalent to the right limit which exists and equals $0$ as you have stated.

Comment: If the function is real-valued, there are no negative values of $x$ to consider, and so the left-sided limit is vacuously true.  If the function is complex-valued, then what you say is correct.

Comment: @Paul: IMO the left-sided limit does not exist at all, as $0$ is not a limit point of the empty set.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the empty set is the counterexample to the equivalence of limit points and $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits.

Comment: @Paul: can you elaborate ?

Comment: Just that the definition will be vacuously statisfied.  "For every $x$ in the domain" will be satisfied because there are no such $x$ in the domain.

Comment: What is variable $\epsilon $ doing in your question? The way you seem to use it makes no sense (at least not in the way limits are used in calculus). What is your intent in introducing this variable?

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Just that I like to use it, no connection to the definition. I think it’s pretty clear how I used it.

Comment: I just want to add this is not standard and perhaps you may not be able to use it in any typical exam. Also where did the $\sin x$ term go?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don’t intend to use it in an exam, although with proper definition it should be perfectly fine. So, $\sin x$ was replaced by $h$ and what I (tried) to show was that $x$ is a little greater than it, and a little less than it in the cases $x\gt 0$ and $x\lt 0$ respectively, as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Replacement of $\sin x$ by $h$ is invalid and a very common mistake. You should avoid non standard approaches otherwise they may lead you to wrong answers. The notation $x\to 0^{+}$ and $x\to 0^{-}$ is sufficient to handle your problem and there is no need to use $h, \epsilon$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Who says it is invalid? It makes perfect sense as in the limit preserves its meaning, and I will use this whenever I please.

Comment: This is simply because one can't replace $A$ by $B$ unless $A=B$. You don't have $\sin h =h$ unless $h=0$.

Comment: Do you intend to replace $\sin x$ by $h$ and $x>\sin x=h$ so write $x=h+\epsilon$. In that case $\epsilon=\arcsin h - h$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Yes, I know. It is a clearer way to represent what’s actually going on as $x\to 0$, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully review the definition of a limit. It states that for $x$ *in the domain* of the function, $0<|x-a|<\delta$ must imply $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

In your example, the limit to $0^+$ does exist and is also the limit to $0$, while the limit to $0^-$ is just irrelevant.

Comment: Yup, I see that now that you point it out.